# Docker error when npm install npm "WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory"

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm

hello im trying to build this docker file

```
FROM node:14.19.2
LABEL author="Salem Alsaggaf"
LABEL description="A react app"
LABEL maintainer="Salem Alsaggaf"
ENV PORT=3000
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
VOLUME [ "/app" ]
RUN  npm install 
EXPOSE $PORT
ENTRYPOINT [ "npm", "start" ]
```

but every time i do a docker build it gives me this error. even though when i run the npm install on my local machine it runs without any problems

```
#13 29.43 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/RightSquareTwoTone.d.ts'
#13 29.43 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/RiseOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.43 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/RiseOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.43 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/RobotFilled.d.ts'
#13 29.43 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/RobotFilled.d.ts'
#13 29.43 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/RobotOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.43 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/RobotOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.43 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/RocketFilled.d.ts'
#13 29.43 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/RocketFilled.d.ts'
#13 29.43 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/RocketOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.43 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/RocketOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.43 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/RocketTwoTone.d.ts'
#13 29.43 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/RocketTwoTone.d.ts'
#13 29.43 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/RollbackOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.43 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/RollbackOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.43 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/RotateLeftOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.43 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/RotateLeftOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.43 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/RotateRightOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.43 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/RotateRightOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.43 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/SafetyCertificateFilled.d.ts'
#13 29.44 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/SafetyCertificateFilled.d.ts'
#13 29.44 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/SafetyCertificateOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.44 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/SafetyCertificateOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.44 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/SafetyCertificateTwoTone.d.ts'
#13 29.44 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/SafetyCertificateTwoTone.d.ts'
#13 29.44 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/SafetyOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.44 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/SafetyOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.44 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/SaveFilled.d.ts'
#13 29.44 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/SaveFilled.d.ts'
#13 29.44 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/SaveOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.44 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/SaveOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.44 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/SaveTwoTone.d.ts'
#13 29.44 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/SaveTwoTone.d.ts'
#13 29.44 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/ScanOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.44 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/ScanOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.44 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/ScheduleFilled.d.ts'
#13 29.44 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/ScheduleFilled.d.ts'
#13 29.44 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/ScheduleOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.44 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/ScheduleOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.44 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/ScheduleTwoTone.d.ts'
#13 29.44 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/ScheduleTwoTone.d.ts'
#13 29.45 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/ScissorOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.45 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/ScissorOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.45 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/SearchOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.45 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/SearchOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.45 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/SecurityScanFilled.d.ts'
#13 29.45 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/SecurityScanFilled.d.ts'
#13 29.45 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/SecurityScanOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.45 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/SecurityScanOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.45 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/SecurityScanTwoTone.d.ts'
#13 29.45 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/SecurityScanTwoTone.d.ts'
#13 29.45 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/SelectOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.45 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/SelectOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.45 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/SendOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.45 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/SendOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.45 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/SettingFilled.d.ts'
#13 29.45 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/SettingFilled.d.ts'
#13 29.45 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/SettingOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.45 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/SettingOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.45 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/SettingTwoTone.d.ts'
#13 29.45 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/SettingTwoTone.d.ts'
#13 29.45 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/ShakeOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.45 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/lib/asn/ShakeOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.45 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-design/icons-svg-a3da9f5f/es/asn/ShareAltOutlined.d.ts'
#13 29.45 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@ant-desi
```

and i tried to run npm install in bash to see last error and it gives me this. please if anyone has any suggestion i am willing to hear them.

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/babar-mythod/react-currency-input.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address '140.82.121.4' to the list of known hosts.
npm ERR! Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

Answer (score 0):

The `VOLUME` line's primary effect is to prevent any `RUN` line after it from having an effect on that directory; that line is preventing the `RUN npm install` step from happening.

Your application code is built into the image, and there's no reason to ask Docker to create anonymous volumes holding it.  Delete that `VOLUME` line.

Even if you do want to replace the code in the image with an entirely different application, missing that `VOLUME` line won't prevent you from `docker run -v` bind-mounting different code over the image.  Unless you're fairly clear on what `VOLUME` does and why you think you need it, it's always safe to leave it out.

Comment: i tried your solution i am still facing the same issue, also the npm install command is definitely running because i can see when i run docker build that it has reached the npm install step. and i really don't understand how my application code i built into the image without using VOLUME